# Pyodbc connect SQL server failed once change SQL server authentication into Azure Active Directory Authentication in Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, ubuntu-16.04, pyodbc

Pyodbc connect SQL server failed once change SQL server authentication into Azure Active Directory Authentication in Ubuntu

I write connection string through the official website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-2017

```
connection_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server={server},1433;Database={db};Uid={userName};Pwd={passWord};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword'
```

It works well in SSMS, and not work with pyodbc in Ubuntu, and it always return below error:

> ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:140A90F1:lib(20):func(169):reason(241)] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I did lots of search about the error, but no a make sense answer.
Can anyone give me some clue about why the error happened? I have been stuck in it a long time

Comment: Have you enabled two factor auth for AD user?

Comment: The `pyodbc` connection string is correct. I connect to my Azure SQL database with Azure Active Directory Authentication successfully in Ubuntu. There must be some error in your Ubuntu environment. It's hard to judge which caused the error.